# Have Django check csrftoken from Cookie instead of POST data or header

Tags: ajax, django, cookies, django-csrf

I have an api on `api.mysite.com` and the frontend on `other.mysite.com` and need AJAX to work, ideally with CSRF protection.

I can a `csrftoken` from an XHR, and it sets the cookie. When I make another XHR with `withCredentials: true`, that new XHR sends the `csrftoken` in the `Cookie` header.

But it seems the Django `CsrfViewMiddleware` only checks if the `csrftoken` is in the POST data, or in the `x-csrftoken` header. It does not check the cookie (if I'm not mistaken).

My problem is that there is no way the Javascript can read the `csrftoken` from the cookie, as it is a cookie from another site.

I see two solutions:

- get an XHR to get a `csrftoken` in the body. That works when I land on the site, but the `csrftoken` can change (if I log out and in I believe)
- have Django read the `csrftoken` from the cookie. This is what I would ideally achieve.

How would I make that work?

Comment: This seems to be a misunderstanding of CSRF protection. The whole point is to check the value in the POST against that in the cookie.

Comment: This is what I was wondering after re-reading the Django docs. So the two tokens (one for the cookie, the other in the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` field) are supposed to be the same, is this what the middleware checks?
So only solution #1 could work?